# ASP.NET assembly vs class library assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Is ASP.NET assembly somehow different from class library assembly? If no is it possible to host class library assembly in IIS?

Comment: No and yes; you can create a DLL (assembly) and, augmenting the code accordingly to support it, expose functions of it with WCF (service). Not sure that's a clever thing to do in your case, you might provide more specific details.

Comment: that's right - there must be some loader to assembly be loaded like Microsoft.Owin.Host.IIS

Answer (score -1):

The resulting assemblies are no different in its nature. There is no magic involed in the process. The only difference related to hosting in IIS is the name of the output directory "bin" instead of "Debug"/"Release" and existance of web.config.

However class library should not be poluted with with hosting related things like specific code or web.config.

Also using ASP.NET project type gives better tooling like F5 (Start debugging) experience.

So hosting class library doesn't make much sense.